# Website content clipping horizontally outside of scrollable area

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML table, when I make my browser window smaller and content has bigger width than browser, I get a horizontal scrollbar, so that I can scroll to content that doesn't fit on screen. However not all of the content width is accessible. Part of my table clips outside of scrollable area to the left. I can scroll from like mid point of table to the complete edge on the right, but I can't get to the left edge. I'm adding screenshots.

[Full width browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cghFP.png)

[Left edge of table in short width browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpHWf.png)

[Right edge of table in short width browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYRF6.png)

I have no idea why I'm unable to scroll all the way to the left edge to the HTML table. Anyone any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post your HTML/CSS. Screenshots do not help us help you. That's like bringing a picture of your car to a mechanic asking them what's wrong with your car. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, Ufon. To get you helped quickly, can you please include a working example as a starting point in code.

Comment: I have a hard time reproducing it on a simple example, but in that intricate site the table was centered with flexbox and after unchecking "align-items: center;" I can scroll correctly.